# Azure Cloud to device telemetry

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub, telemetry, s7-1200

Hello dear  community

Could you help us with the following:

We are doing a "D2C telemetry and C2D" project  and using MQQT protocol. We are able to transfer data from the device PLC S7 through a IBHLINK OPC Server (mqtt based messages) to our IoT hub and via StreamAnalysys to visualize it on Power Bi.

Now we need to process the data and send it back to the device. Initial tags should be pushed in a formula and then the online results are needed back to the "Plant". We are considering the following  approach:

to set " Service bus" or maybe an Event Hub  connected to the IotHub-  to make a queue or a "storage" respectively and then to specify a "function " triggered by ......possible are: new Event hub event, new Queue message, new Service bus message/topic.

What could be the easiest solution for that? Have you seen any appropriate examples? Could we make our calculation inside the function and directly forward it back or we need a specific resource?

To control the device from the Azure side (PLC Siemens S7 1200 ),  do we need an alternative method?  for example,  to restart or shutdown the PLC by sending a specific boolean value to the OPC server.  I have heard about the"direct method". Could you give any ideas or examples, as well?

Thank you in advance

Best regards